# ffmpeg crop pixels only from the top

Tags: ffmpeg

The closest thing I found is this command `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter:v "crop=in_w:in_h-40" -c:a copy out.mp4`
, which crops the video 20px from the top and 20px from the bottom.

What's the command to only crop from the top? I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter:v "crop=in_w:in_h-40:0:out_h" -c:a copy out.mp4
```

You need to declare the `y` position because the default (for both `x` and `y`) is centered. See the [crop filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) for more info.

Comment: This crops pixels from the bottom to me, I need something from the top

Comment: y  should be `ih-oh`